# jsp to display alert

Tags: javascript, security, jsp, jsp-tags

How do i write a Jsp page which opens JSbox.

main vulnerabilities that apply to this eg.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to worry about the cross-site-scripting problems caused by HTML and JS injection. CSRF doesn't seem to be an issue yet because just alerting “hello” doesn't have any active side-effects that you would have to be logged in to do.

The bonehead way of doing it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Hello, <%= request.getParameter("name") %>');
</script>
```

This suffers from JS injection because there is no JS-escaping inside a JS string literal:

```
name=');execute_arbitrary_code();'
```

and also suffers HTML injection because the enclosing script block can be closed early:

```
name=</script><script>execute_arbitrary_code();//
```

Unfortunately there is no standard tag in JSP that will escape text in a JS string literal (that is itself in an HTML script block). You can write and use your own tag to do it, or reuse a library that defines one. For example OWASP ESAPI has:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Hello, <esapi:encodeForJavaScript>${param.name}</esapi:encodeForJavaScript>');
</script>
```

But it is often easier to avoid encoding into JS, and instead push data through the DOM. Because the DOM is plain HTML, you only need normal markup escaping, which JSP has natively in the `<c:out>` tag.

```
<input type="hidden" id="name-parameter" value="<c:out value="${param.name}"/>"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = document.getElementById('name-parameter').value;
    alert('Hello, '+name);
</script>
```

This aids in the long-term goal of keeping your JS separate from your markup and server-side code. `data-` attributes are another good way to pass data from markup to JS.